# What is SOLIX_TAB (SAP)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, abap, sap-data-dictionary

I want to know, what is `SOLIX_TAB` ?

What type of conversion methodology should be used ?

How to decrypt or export it as a PDF in C# or VB.NET ?

**EDIT** (text taken from OP comment):

> *"I am accessing a SAP Function, which return the employee information in a Format:Solix_TAB. It contains all the information related to the employee including lines, spaces & texts. I want to convert that solix_tab to PDF."*

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am accessing a SAP Function, which return the employee information in a Format:Solix_TAB. It contains all the information related to the employee including lines, spaces & texts. I want to convert that solix_tab to PDF.

Comment: `SOLIX_TAB` is a table containing bytes. It may contain many different formats (PDF, image, sound, video, text, SAP-proprietary formats, etc.) Please show its content and ABAP developers can tell you what it is about. Also please tell us which SAP Function you access.

Answer (score 1):

SOLIX_TAB is a SAP internal table structure, containing lines with 255 bytes of raw data (binary; SAP internal type: SO_RAW255). I guess, you try to access SAP by using RFC calling some function module which returns a table of type SOLIX_TAB. Just concatenate the table lines and you will get a binary string containing your PDF file. It's usually not encrypted anyway. Just store the string to some file named *.pdf an try to open it.